# Game State manager, pausing and resuming

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

I am attempting to allow for pauses in my game. Currently, I have a change state which works well. For the Pausing I have:

```
void PushState(int newState)
{
    pauseID = stateID; ///save state number

    Gstates.push_back(currentState); ///Set Current state to vector

    nextState =  newState; ///acquire new state

    switch( nextState )
    {
    case STATE_INTRO:
        currentState = new CIntroState(); ///create new state
        break;
    }

    //Change the current state ID
    stateID = nextState;

    //NULL the next state ID
    nextState = STATE_NULL;
}
```

The above part seems to work well.

This is my resume section

```
void Resuming()
{
    nextState = pauseID;

    if( nextState != STATE_EXIT )
    {
         delete currentState; ///deletes current state
    }

    switch( nextState )
    {
    case STATE_INTRO:
        currentState = Gstates.back(); ///sets current state to the saved state
        Gstates.pop_back(); ///delets saved state 
        break;
    }

    //Change the current state ID
    stateID = nextState;

    //NULL the next state ID
    nextState = STATE_NULL;
}
```

I get some weird multi threading error. about 50% of the time it works as intended lol, but the rest of the time it crashes.

The error basically says, "Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called.

The client is not multi threaded ;).. Anyway, does anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/XInitThreads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some dangerous code there. This:

```
if( nextState != STATE_EXIT )
{
     delete currentState; ///deletes current state
}
```

will leave your "currentState" pointing to non-existent object, because it is only updated if nextState is STATE_INTRO:

```
switch( nextState )
{
case STATE_INTRO:
    currentState = Gstates.back(); ///sets current state to the saved state
    Gstates.pop_back(); ///delets saved state 
    break;
}
```

This could very well be the reason for crashes.

Comment: ya, I think that is what is causing the crashes too. I am not sure why though. The whole idea was to save the old currentState, run the new currentState, than revert back to the old currentState. Maybe I need to use something other than a vector to store the object?

Comment: but do you revert to currentState? Are you certain that when Resuming is executed, 'nextState', which is restored from pauseID is STATE_INTRO? Because in pushState you save copy stateID to pauseID and if I understand logic correctly, it is the ID of the running state, and thus probably is _not_ STATE_INTRO.

Comment: I have done some couts and the value held is pauseID and it is State_Intro. pauseID was meant to store the value of the state being saved. In this instance it is intro state because I am only working with that one active state. I have a counter increasing, so I switch states and watch the counter start over. Than resume paused state and see if the counter continues.